# Max IOPS/Max throughput for S3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see a lot of information on EBS volume types and its max IOPS / max throughput but not any information on S3.
Can someone help me find out what is the maximum IOPS / max throughput for aws S3? And is the max IOPS limit per bucket or per account?

Answer (score 7):

EBS is block storage attached to an EC2 instance. S3 is object storage that you connect to over the Internet. You aren't going to get an IOPS metric for S3. I don't think they publish a max throughput/max transmission rate value for S3. I would suggest reading this page in the S3 documentation: [Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html). You could also look into S3 Transfer Acceleration, or CloudFront for increased transfer rate.

Comment: It answered my concerns. Thank you!

Comment: @SundarRamaPenumarthi See that checkBox on the left? You can click that one to accept the answer.